# MSSQL How do I get average of four records from different tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have four tables and I need to find the average of each score for a particular id. I do not need the ENTIRE Column average, but the average of each record with the same id in each table.
I have tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  M.system_id, S.name, SUM(A.Score + WAL.score + F.score + WIN.score) / 4 
AS avgScore 
FROM         dbo.T3_MovementSystemJoin AS M 
INNER JOIN dbo.T3_systems AS S ON M.system_id = S.id
INNER JOIN T3_ApplicationSystemJoin AS A ON A.Application_id = @application_id
INNER JOIN T3_WallTypeSystemJoin AS WAL ON WAL.wall_id = @wall_id
INNER JOIN T3_FenestrationSystemJoin AS F ON F.fenestration_id = @fen_id
INNER JOIN T3_WindowOrientation_System AS WIN ON WIN.window_id = @window_id
INNER JOIN T3_ConstructionSystemJoin AS C ON C.contruction_id = @construction_id
INNER JOIN T3_JointDepthSystemJoin AS J ON J.JointDepth_id = @JointDepth_id
INNER JOIN T3_JointGapSystemJoin AS JG ON JG.JointGap_id = @JointGap_id
WHERE     (M.movement_id = @movement_id)
GROUP BY M.System_id, S.name
```

:

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and desired results?  What does "the average of each record with the same id in each table" really mean in terms of the output result set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No `Sum` needed (and no grouping too)

```
SELECT DISTINCT  M.system_id, S.name,  (IsNull(A.Score, 0) +   IsNull(WAL.score, 0) +  IsNull(F.score, 0) +  IsNull(WIN.score, 0)) /4
as avgscore
FROM         dbo.T3_MovementSystemJoin AS M 
INNER JOIN dbo.T3_systems AS S ON M.system_id = S.id
INNER JOIN T3_ApplicationSystemJoin AS A ON A.Application_id = @application_id
INNER JOIN T3_WallTypeSystemJoin AS WAL ON WAL.wall_id = @wall_id
INNER JOIN T3_FenestrationSystemJoin AS F ON F.fenestration_id = @fen_id
INNER JOIN T3_WindowOrientation_System AS WIN ON WIN.window_id = @window_id
INNER JOIN T3_ConstructionSystemJoin AS C ON C.contruction_id = @construction_id
INNER JOIN T3_JointDepthSystemJoin AS J ON J.JointDepth_id = @JointDepth_id
INNER JOIN T3_JointGapSystemJoin AS JG ON JG.JointGap_id = @JointGap_id
WHERE     (M.movement_id = @movement_id)
```

Comment: I tried that and it gave me less errors, however It continues to return the entire 'avgscore' column as NULL

Comment: probably because one or more of the columns is null, I've changed the code a bit. When you do `4 + null` in will return `null` so we use `Isnull` to help with this,

Comment: Actually, It is working now...Wrong sample data...Thanks A bunch!

Comment: @user1080618 . . . Why would you want the average to divide by "4" if there are missing values?

Comment: They are not missing values, I imputed the incorrect data

Comment: @user1080618 What happens if at some point you do have a missing value?  Is that really the same as a zero score?  Do you want it included in the average?

Comment: That is a problem with the data, the integrity of the data is not of my responsibility, however I do appreciate your concerns

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT M.system_id
,S.name
,(ISNULL(A.Score,0) + ISNULL(WAL.score,0) + ISNULL(F.score,0) + ISNULL(WIN.score,0)) /4 as 'AvgScore'
FROM         dbo.T3_MovementSystemJoin AS M 
INNER JOIN dbo.T3_systems AS S ON M.system_id = S.id
INNER JOIN T3_ApplicationSystemJoin AS A ON A.Application_id = @application_id
INNER JOIN T3_WallTypeSystemJoin AS WAL ON WAL.wall_id = @wall_id
INNER JOIN T3_FenestrationSystemJoin AS F ON F.fenestration_id = @fen_id
INNER JOIN T3_WindowOrientation_System AS WIN ON WIN.window_id = @window_id
INNER JOIN T3_ConstructionSystemJoin AS C ON C.contruction_id = @construction_id
INNER JOIN T3_JointDepthSystemJoin AS J ON J.JointDepth_id = @JointDepth_id
INNER JOIN T3_JointGapSystemJoin AS JG ON JG.JointGap_id = @JointGap_id
WHERE     (M.movement_id = @movement_id)
```

Comment: Like I said, I do not need the average of the entire column

Comment: Providing sample data and results would be helpful then because you said 'average of each score'.  Edited answer with what I think you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want NULL values to become zeros and included in the average:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  M.system_id, S.name, X.avgScore
FROM         dbo.T3_MovementSystemJoin AS M 
INNER JOIN dbo.T3_systems AS S ON M.system_id = S.id
INNER JOIN T3_ApplicationSystemJoin AS A ON A.Application_id = @application_id
INNER JOIN T3_WallTypeSystemJoin AS WAL ON WAL.wall_id = @wall_id
INNER JOIN T3_FenestrationSystemJoin AS F ON F.fenestration_id = @fen_id
INNER JOIN T3_WindowOrientation_System AS WIN ON WIN.window_id = @window_id
INNER JOIN T3_ConstructionSystemJoin AS C ON C.contruction_id = @construction_id
INNER JOIN T3_JointDepthSystemJoin AS J ON J.JointDepth_id = @JointDepth_id
INNER JOIN T3_JointGapSystemJoin AS JG ON JG.JointGap_id = @JointGap_id
CROSS APPLY ( SELECT AVG(s) FROM (VALUES (A.Score),(WAL.score),(F.score),(WIN.score) ) scores(s) ) X(avgScore)
WHERE     (M.movement_id = @movement_id)
GROUP BY M.System_id, S.name
```